# About importing locally and from the web in the tag <script>

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, frontend

Extremelly basic question here.

I'm a really noob front-end developer and I always had this question.
Some "tools" (frameworks, libs and stuffs) that we import to our website via `<script src="xxxx">` are constantly used. Like Jquery and others.

But when I visit **Jquery** website, for example, I don't see any instructions to import via url - they only give the option to download the framework and, with that, we link our website to the framework locally. `<script src='../scripts/jquery.js'>` instead of `<script src='https://www.someWebSite.com.br/jquery.min.js'>`

But a lot of websites link their projects to Jquery via url.

So here's my question - how can I find these URLs easilly to import in our websites instead of downloading the whole file? (**Jquery** was only an example. **Jquery masked input** is other example. I couldn't find any URL on their website. )

Sorry about the basic question.

Answer (score 0):

Web servers also have a file system like a normal workstation, the JQuery javascript file is located somewhere in the server and you can link it to using `src` attribute.

Most of the servers don't have directory browsing enabled (for security reasons, FTP sites are a good choice), so you can't browse the server for the `.js` files unless their links are shared publicly in any web page.